# spit out database fields from bottom-up for a blog posting system

Tags: php, content-management-system, blogs, output

I have a php code which also includes pagination

```
<?php
//to make pagination
$statement = "`blog_posts`";
        //show users
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo '
            <div class="box">
            <a class="title" href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a>
            <hr/>
            <p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <hr/>
            <div class="desc">
            Posted on '.date("jS M Y H:i:s", strtotime($row["postDate"])).'
            <div class="underside"><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></div>
            </div>
            </div>              
            ';
        }

echo pagination($statement,$limit,$page);
```

If I was to have three posts like so...

```
ID      TITLE
-------------
1       Apples
2       Post 2
3       Grapes
```

My blog would spit them out like so...

```
Apples
Post 2
Grapes
```

This is bad because the newest posts are at the very bottom of the page (or at the last page)

I want it so that the newest articles appear first.

How would I do this. Please help explain why my current code isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM {$statement} ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}
```

Where date should be the date, blog was saved

Comment: WOW, Thanks to everyone that answered this. I thought it would be alot more confusing :P

Answer (score 0):

change your query like below and add order by

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} ORDER BY id desc LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please, use order by column for sorting as per desc or asc order :

 <?php
    //to make pagination
    $statement = "`blog_posts`";
            //show users
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$statement} ORDER BY date desc LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo '
                <div class="box">
                <a class="title" href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a>
                <hr/>
                <p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <hr/>
                <div class="desc">
                Posted on '.date("jS M Y H:i:s", strtotime($row["postDate"])).'
                <div class="underside"><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></div>
                </div>
                </div>              
                ';
            }

    echo pagination($statement,$limit,$page);
```